# Setting a value of an object's child property problem

Tags: .net, components

I get child properties of an object with this code,

PropertyDescriptorCollection childProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(theObject)[childNode.Name].GetChildProperties();

think that "theObject" variable is a TextBox and I try to set TextBox.Font.Bold = true;

I use this code for main properties and it works when I customize for main properties. But when I access the child properties,

I get an error which is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor childProperty in childProperties)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (childProperty.Name == attribute.Name)
                {

                    if (!childProperty.IsReadOnly)
                    {

                        object convertedPropertyValue = ConverterHelper.ConvertValueForProperty(attribute.Value, childProperty);

                        childProperty.SetValue(theObject, convertedPropertyValue); //exception throw here

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the full exception please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the wrong object to `SetValue` - on the face of it it looks like you get something like:

```
<TextBox>
  <Font Bold="true"/>
</Textbox>
```

And then you get the `Font` property of the text box and the `Bold` property of the font and then you try to assign the value `true` to the `Bold` property of `TextBox`. Obviously this is not going to work.

Maybe something like this:

```
PropertyDescriptor objProp = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(theObject)[childNode.Name];
PropertyDescriptorCollection childProperties = objProp.GetChildProperties();

foreach (PropertyDescriptor childProperty in childProperties) {
    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attributes) {
        if (childProperty.Name == attribute.Name && !childProperty.IsReadOnly) {
            Object convertedPropertyValue = converterHelper.ConvertValueForProperty(attribute.Value, childProperty);
            childProperty.SetValue(objProp.getValue(theObject), convertedPropertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the context for setting properties of the child object is the child object and not the parent object.

Comment: I can get attributes and values from xml. there is no problem there but now I get this error : "Object does not match target type." when SetValue method.

Comment: I think I found my mistake, and I assumed that childObject is the instance of `Font` but it is not. I've reedited the answer, try it this time.